# Change Hosts file based on connection - Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, dns, hosts

So I have a laptop. It connects to places wirelessly. Home, work and public. I want to change the host file based on the network I'm connected too.

Realistically, in my situation, I should have 2 sets of IPs:

Home Network (Inside Network):

```
192.168.1.101 HomePC
192.168.1.102 HomePrinter
```

Home Network (Outside Network):

```
1.2.3.4 HomePC
1.2.3.5 HomePrinter
```

Work (Inside Network):

```
192.168.50.101 WorkPC
192.168.50.102 WorkPrinter
```

Work (Outside Network):

```
70.2.3.4 WorkPC
70.2.3.5 WorkPrinter
```

I need an easy way to toggle between the 3 states, preferably automatically based on Hotspot I'm connected too.

Powershell scripts, open-source, etc preferred, but I'm not adverse to spending if the best tool is affordable

Answer (score 1):

So far here is what I found:

- [Mobile Net Switcher](http://www.mobilenetswitch.com/Order/), which does much more than just switching hosts file. It costs 29€.
- [Switch Location](http://www.kevinblake.co.uk/switch-location/) (*developed by Kevin Blake*), which is totally free, but seems to be crashing on Windows 8.1 x64.

Did you find anything else?